# Eclipse Welcome-page plugin: How to open relative path on external browser from Intro.xml

Tags: java, url, eclipse-plugin, relative-path

How can to open a url on external browser using a relative path from a customized Eclipse Welcome page plugin?

The following code is an example of what I have so far from the intro.xml, which is working OK for Linux but doesn't work for Windows.

```
             <link 
                label="Documentation" 
                url="http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/openBrowser?url=file:../documentation/index.html"   
                id="link-img-documentation" 
                style-id="content-link">
              <text>Read documentation.</text>
             </link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative way is to use `http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/runAction` and create a class that implements `IIntroAction`
Overall, you will need to do two things.

- Add a class that implements `IIntroAction`

```
public class OpenFileInBrowser implements IIntroAction {
    @Override
    public void run(IIntroSite site, Properties params) {
        
        if (params.containsKey("filePath") ){
            String filePath = params.getProperty("filePath");
            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            String urlString = "file://" + workingDir + File.separator + filePath;
            
            try {
                IWorkbenchBrowserSupport browserSupport = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport();
                IWebBrowser browser = browserSupport.getExternalBrowser();
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                browser.openURL(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

- Update *url* in the link tag as following:

```
 url="http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/runAction?pluginId=x.y.z&amp;class=x.y.z.OpenFileInBrowser&amp;filePath=../documentation/index.html"
```